# Manejar horarios en firebase

Tags: nodejs, firebase, angular, ionic, backend

Estoy realizando una tarea para la universidad utilizando la base de datos en tiempo real de Firebase en Ionic y Angular 2. No tengo ningún problema en el típico crud, pero me es necesario hacer un cambio de un dato de la base de datos, y un cierto tiempo después (una hora, por ejemplo) volver a cambiar el valor. 
Hay alguna forma de actualizar un dato en un tiempo programado en firebase usando(corrijanme si me equivoco) su backend? 
Esta acción debería ser propia de firebase. Les comento que no tengo mucho conocimiento de firebase en este aspecto.
Espero se haya entendido el problema. Muchas gracias de antemano.
[añado esto]: La duda también esta en cual evento usar para iniciar esta tarea, la idea de esto es modificar un valor de un nodo(onChange) y 20 min después volverlo a su estado original. Viendo esa lógica, al activarlo con el cambio, no sé como volver a cambiar el dato. Podría usar un setTimeout para ejecutar el cambio 20 minutos después, pero no afectaría el rendimiento? Y más teniendo en cuenta que tengo el plan gratuito de firebase

Comment: Si estas usando firebase, podes agregar un trigger en la base de datos en tiempo real usando cloudfunctions que guarde el estado proximo en algun lugar y al mismo tiempo lanze otra function que ejecute dentro de una hora para volver a cambiar la base de datos.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Quizas te interese averiguar sobre cloud functions , esto se programa en javascript y corre del lado del servidor, como no tenemos que montar ningun servidor, decimos que es serverless. Aca te dejo un video que hice de como implementar una funcion a firebase que corre del lado del servidor

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vsQw-1zS3mY

De la misma forma que en el video se puede configurar para trabajar con timestamps y hacer cosas a partir de distintos tiempos (cron jobs). Te dejo el repo de todas las functions publicas hasta el momento, siguiendo el video podes implementar cualquiera. Ademas este video de como usar cron jobs con functions es muy bueno  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fEBPAMSk5_8

https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples